# How to intercept springfox-swagger json generation?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm using `springfox-swagger`  for autogeneration of `@RestController` documentation.

In one application I want to manually rewrite some of the urls of my exposed endpoints. Thus I somehow have to intercept the swagger json generation process. But how?

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
   @GetMapping("/test")
   public Object test(String param) {
      ...
   }
}
```

This autogenerates a path eg:

```
{
 "paths":{
      "/test":...
 }
}
```

I want to modify this path to a different one for the swagger ui documentation. But how can I override it? (as I cannot override it by annotation using `@ApiOperation`).